# How to install Neo4j on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-16.04

I can't get the Neo4j service to start on Ubuntu 16.04. A while ago I was running a Ubuntu 14 and I was able to install Neo4j just fine. But then I removed it and time passed and I've upgraded to Ubuntu 16 and now I want to check out Neo4j again and it's not installing. I have java and anything it asks me. I'm little aware that that Ubuntu changed the service launcher and I think that might be it but I don't know enough in either Ubuntu or Neo4j to know where to start debugging to figure out how to make this work.

Can someone point me to logs to look at or can they fill in any holes in my knowledge to help me?

UPDATE

```
michael@Acer:~$ systemctl status neo4j
● neo4j.service - LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/neo4j; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-09-27 13:56:05 MDT; 3 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 37
   Memory: 120.3M
      CPU: 46min 31.410s
   CGroup: /system.slice/neo4j.service
           └─17663 /usr/bin/java -cp             /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/    * -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThr

Oct 01 11:44:53 Acer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server.
Oct 01 11:45:00 Acer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is     incomplete or unavailable.
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Here is the info from the firewall:

```
 netstat -ntlp | grep 17663
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7473          :::*                    LISTEN      17663/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7474          :::*                    LISTEN      17663/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:1337          :::*                    LISTEN      17663/java
tcp6       0      0 :::42787                :::*                    LISTEN      17663/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7687          :::*                    LISTEN      17663/java
```

Comment: A difference is the init system  `upstart` has usually been replaced by `systemd`, maybe that's it? What does a `systemctl status neo4j` do, or `systemctl start neo4j` show you?

Comment: Here is the output, if I'm reading this right, it's running. But when trying to get to the browser <ip.address>:7474 I get a timeout exception. Do I have to create a firewall rule to allow traffic through?

Comment: Well, for my part, that means is running with PID 17663. Probably it listens to localhost only though, which IP address are you accessing, and what does `netstat -ntlp | grep 17663` show you? If you're running a firewall, and you're using the correct IP, the output of `iptables-save` might be interesting too.

Comment: I've posted the netstat and I ran the iptables-save but didn't post the output because it's a little longer. But in that output I didn't see anything that was a local ip, or the 7474 ports.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! I had to allow non-local access to Neo4j.

In the previous versions of Neo4j, the default installation would allow remote connections. Since I've always installed this on a headless server, I just assumed this was how it is. In the new Neo4j 3.0, this is turned off by default and you have to go into neo4j.config and uncomment the appropriate lines in the networking section to allow connections. Made the config changes and reboot the machine just for good measure and everything started to work.

Comment: The file is `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` and the lines to uncomment are 

    `dbms.shell.enabled=true`
    `dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1`
    `dbms.shell.port=1337`

Comment: @Radu: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be valid any more. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and neo4j 3.5.3 and there is no `*.shell.*` property anywhere. Adding them didn't work either.

Comment: @ChrisTophski they've updated the configuration, check out the latest documentation for enabling remote connections https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/

Comment: @MichaelBlack thanks for the hint. Meanwhile I also tried some `*.browser.*` settings I found somewhere. As this didn't work either, I figured it out using `*.dbms.connector.*` settings as described on the page you linked. This works now.